# HSEARCH700061: Unable to index-embed type 'java.lang.String':

Tags: hibernate, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

Can someone please help us why we are getting below exceptions in hibernate-search 6?

```
failures: 
              - HSEARCH700061: Unable to index-embed type 'java.lang.String': no index mapping (@GenericField, @FullTextField, custom bridges, ...) is defined for that type.
```

and

```
HSEARCH400520: Duplicate index field definition: 'users'. Index field names must be unique. Look for two property mappings with the same field name, or two indexed-embeddeds with prefixes that lead to conflicting index field names, or two custom bridges declaring index fields with the same name.
```

I am using these two annotations together like:

```
@IndexedEmbedded
@GenericField
private Set<String> users;
```

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/migration/html_single/#indexedembeded-containerextraction

Comment: Hi @yrodiere -In Hibernate Search 6, annotation IndexedEmbedded should no longer be used this way
does it mean we can not put these two annotations together for my case??

If yes,if I removed IndexedEmbedded then getting below error

HSEARCH800007: Unable to resolve path '. to a persisted attribute in Hibernate ORM metadata. If this path points to a transient attribute, use IndexingDependency(derivedFrom = ...) to specify which persisted attributes it is derived from. See the reference documentation for more information.

can you please help us here?